# RObject.isExists() check on memory or on server?

Tags: java, redisson

The code bellow threw a NullPointerException just once.

```
    public Optional<Object> getBucketObject(String key) {
        return getKey(key, client::getBucket, RBucket::get);
    }

    public Optional<Long> getLong(String key) {
        return getKey(key, client::getAtomicLong, RAtomicLong::get);
    }

    public Optional<Double> getDouble(String key) {
        return getKey(key, client::getAtomicDouble, RAtomicDouble::get);
    }


public <T, K extends RObject> Optional<T> getKey(String key, Function<String, K> getMethod, Function<K, T> returnMethod) {
        K cachedObj = getMethod.apply(key);

        return
            cachedObj.isExists()
                ? Optional.of(returnMethod.apply(cachedObj)) (***line 50)
                : Optional.empty();
    }
```

This is the stacktrace:

```
java.util.Objects.requireNonNull (Objects.java:203)
java.util.Optional.<init> (Optional.java:96)
java.util.Optional.of (Optional.java:108)
xxx.xxx.getKey (xxx.java:50)
```

I was wondering how this is possible. The only possibility I have found is that between isExists() and apply() the key was removed in the server. But it will only make sense if the method isExists() checks in the server, instead of check in RAM.

I tried to search in redisson documentation but nothing is said about if it is checked on server or ram.

https://javadoc.io/doc/org.redisson/redisson/3.3.2/org/redisson/api/RObject.html#isExists--

Answer (score 0):

According to Redis [commands mapping list](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/11.-Redis-commands-mapping) `RObject.isExists()` bounded to `EXISTS` Redis command